# MMS vCard displaying as playable media file

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, cyanogenmod, mms, vcard

I am having difficulty viewing a vcard received via text message.  My phone recognizes it's an  MMS but views it as a Multimedia file and tries to play it.

My phone is rooted running Cyanogen 7.0.1.2 and I'm using the builtin messaging app

I have taken a screenshot of what I'm experiencing
http://dumpt.com/img/files/hz9oupxkp9g5myy9tu5z.jpg

Comment: In my case I got a vcard sent from an iPhone, and it just displays as text (BEGIN: VCARD VERSION:3.0 PRODID:-//Apple Inc./iOS 5.0.1//).  I'm running stock Android 2.3.4 on a MyTouch 4g slide phone.  I see no way to save it.  Silly....

Comment: This subsequent question has more information: [MMS images showing up as videos - Android - Stack Exchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11460/mms-images-showing-up-as-videos)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to long-press and save the .vcard to your SD card, then open it in a file manager, like [File Expert](https://market.android.com/details?id=xcxin.filexpert&feature=search_result). If you still cannot read the file after viewing it from one of these channels, then your system can probably not view files in this format and i would try downloading a .vcard viewer, if such a thing exists.

Comment: How do you save a text message in a file?  Long press on the message text relates to selected text, and doesn't give a save option - it offers stuff like "copy", "quick lookup", at least on android 2.3.4.  It takes careful work to select the vcard text, and then e.g. paste into an email message, but that doesnt' come across as a vcard.  Short press offers stuff like "forward", but only to another SMS recipient, not to e.g. email

Answer (score 0):

Try using Handcent SMS - it now has support for displaying business card format. If a similar problem occurs, perhaps it'd due to the vcard itself?

Comment: I've received more than one that behaves this way.  I just wanted the stock messaging program to work.  Even after clean install it still does the same thing.

Comment: The Handcent SMS app says it handles vcards, but for me it just shows an empty message - even worse than the stock messaging program which at least lets me copy/paste the text of the vcard.