# MMS images showing up as videos

Tags: nexus-one, mms, att

For some reason when receiving pictures from people with iPhones, they sometimes show up as a video.  The video is usually 20 seconds long with the first half blank (sometimes there is text depending on how the person sent the message) and the second half contains the picture (though it is really small).  Any idea what is going on here?  Googling didn't really turn up anything so I suspect this is only happening with the AT&T version of the Nexus One with MMS sent from AT&T iPhones or something.  This has happened since 2.1-update1 when I first got the phone and still happens now (running 2.3.4 stock Google OS, unrooted).

OK, I did find some other people with similar issues:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/android/thread?tid=0e35a68a13fb466f&hl=en

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/android/thread?tid=1b552b9e6595a79d&hl=en

Does anyone know of a way to workaround this?  It's really quite annoying.  Even a bug number in Google's issue tracking system would at least give me some hope that this would get fixed.

Comment: This happens for me with images sent from an iPhone 4 on Verizon to a Droid Charge on Verizon. So this case can't be blamed on the network. Its really annoying though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might have something to do with a feature of MMS called Content adaptation. Your operator's MMSC (Multimedia Messaging Service Center) determines if the data sent is in a format supported by your handset, and if not, transcodes it into another format. This can cause some problems between different devices and operators. For example, my Android receives single images from other Android phones as 10 second videos where 1st half is the image and 2nd half is the message.

At least here in Finland, the behaviour I described is pretty standard and has happened since the days MMS was made available and people are used to it (as far as I know). Don't know about AT&T, but I'd suspect there won't be any changes in the near future.

Comment: I see.  So this is really AT&T being stupid thinking they need to modify the format of MMS because they don't think the receiving phone can support it?  They probably just send it as-is when they know the receiving phone is an iPhone.  Damn you AT&T!

Answer (score 0):

I found on another site that if you save it and view it from your downloads folder, it displays as a normal photo.